# ¿Cuál de esas frases es correcta? ("en que" vs. "donde")

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática

Which of these forms is correct, better?

> Vivo en lo mismo lugar en que vivía hace un año

vs

> Vivo en lo mismo lugar donde vivía hace un año

Or maybe both are fine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the correction of `lo` for `el`, both

> Vivo en **el** mismo lugar **donde** vivía hace un año

and

> Vivo en **el** mismo lugar **en que** vivía hace un año

are correct. So, both are fine and there is actually no "better".

Comment: This answer is correct and I only want to add that the second sentence I would say it like this "Vivo en el mismo lugar en EL que vivía hace un año". That is a more common way around here.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference is the preposition used.  The difference is very literal, even if translated

> I live in the same place in which I lived a year ago

vs.

> I live in the same place where I lived a year ago.

To answer your question:

### With the exception of `lo` (which should be `el`), they're both correct.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of your example sentences sounds right, but the second one with the change from `en que` to `donde` definitely sounds better.

I would also change `lo` to `el` and remove `mismo` because it's redundant.

You can't always do this, but think about the English translation for this example:

> I live in the same place where I lived a year ago.
>
> *Yo vivo en el mismo lugar donde vivía hace un año.*

---

> I live in the place where I lived a year ago.
>
> *Yo vivo en el lugar donde vivía hace un año.*

---

Or you could even further simplify:

> I live where I lived a year ago.
>
> *Yo vivo donde vivía hace un año.*

---

**(EDIT)** And *even* further by eliminating `yo` (suggested by Martin Argerami and Kray12321):

> I live where I lived a year ago.
>
> *Vivo donde vivía hace un año.*

Comment: I would suggest eliminating the "yo". Kray12321's answer explains it perfectly.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You're absolutely right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Usar "en que" o "en el que" también es correcto

Answer (score 2):

I'd go even further with the further simplification, and eliminate "yo":

> Vivo donde vivía hace un año.

I'd use "yo" only if I wanted to emphasize it in some way.  E.g., perhaps someone just told me that they live in a different place (now) than where they lived a year ago.  If I want to emphasize MY different experience, I might say  "Yo" vivo donde vivía hace un año.

Answer (score 2):

You have to say

> Vivo en **EL** mismo lugar + en que vivía hace un año

or

> Vivo en **EL** mismo lugar donde vivía hace un año

Both are correct, but you have to use `el` since is a "male sustantive", most of all used for the ones ending in `L, -O, -N, -E, -R, -S;` (in this case, lugaR)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any of those, aside from the fact stated in previous answers where "lo" should be "el" they are right.

I would use:

> Sigo viviendo en el mismo sitio del año pasado

or

> Sigo viviendo donde el año pasado

But depending on the question maybe another answers would fit better:

¿Donde estas viviendo?

> En el mismo sitio del año pasado

or

> Sigo en el mismo sitio

or

> Donde el año pasado